# .map producing a wrongly shaped polygon points list

Tags: d3.js

Actually this is maybe more of a Javascript question, but since I came across the problem while coding in d3, and since it only occurs in IE9, I think it is especially relevant to d3 users.

Here is what I do:
I start out adding mouse clicks to an array:

```
daLineArray.push({ x: d3.mouse(this)[0], y: d3.mouse(this)[1] });
```

From this I generate a path, by feeding the resulting array into the
d3.svg.line generator. This works well in all browsers.

Then I turn the path into a polygon by first mapping the original array
into a shorter one:

```
daLineArrayShort = daLineArray.map(function(d) { return d3.values(d) });
```

and then feeding this into the d3.area generator.

This produces a fine polygon in all browsers with the exception of IE9,
which complains about the points list not having the proper form.

And to be honest, IE9 is right.

When I check the resulting polygon in its html form it looks like this (the
numbers being fictional in this case):

```
points="10,10,20,20,30,30,40,40,etcetera"
```

While I guess it should be looking like this:

```
points="10,10 20,20 30,30 40,40 etcetera"
```

In other words there is a comma between the coordinate pairs where a space
is expected.

I had noticed this before, but I only realized it was a problem when I
tested my work in IE9.

So, my question is: how do I produce a properly parsed array?

(I did try pushing the points directly onto `daLineArrayShort
(.push([d3.event.pageX, d3.event.pageY])`, but that didn't produce the
proper points list either - the comma keeps propping up.)

Answer (score 0):

Resolved over in the google d3 group by Alexander Skarburskis:

http://groups.google.com/group/d3-js/browse_thread/thread/10387708619aab34